# SQL: Sum prices based on price category

Tags: sql

I have a problem regarding calculating earnings based on prices and prize categories. This is a table for prices at a cinema:

```
Prices           
Movie              Regular        Student
Batman             8.50            7.50
Spiderman          6.50            6.00
The Godfather      5.50            4.50
.......
```

This is a table for booked customers:

```
Customers
Name            Movie         Date               Price
Dennis Jones    Batman      2014-12-01           Student
Al McGregor     Spiderman   2014-12-01           Regular
Lee Wong        Batman      2014-12-01           Regular
.......
```

Based on this, how do I calculate the future earnings of Batman at  2014-12-01, with an SQL query?

Hank

Comment: Why for the love of god did you put `Date` and `Time` in separate fields. That complicates this issue so incredibly. SQL supports `datetime` fields for good reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is basically a `join` with conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when price = 'Student' then Student
                when price = 'Regular' then Regular
           end)
from customers c join
     prices p
     on c.movie = p.movie
where date = '2014-12-01' and time = '1200' and Movie = 'Batman';
```

A comment about the data structure.  Your tables should have primary keys, which are normally auto-incremented integers, rather than being combined using strings.  There is no problem separating date and time, as you have done, especially for something like movies where the "time" represents slots on each day.

Comment: +1 Ideally, Prices should have 2 columns, Movie and PriceCategory

Answer (score 1):

I would probably go with something like the following:

```
Select Movie, MovieDate, MovieTime, Sum(PriceToPay)
from
(Select P.Movie, P.Regular, P.Student, C.Name, C.Date as MovieDate, C.Time as MovieTime, (Case  when C.Price = 'Student' then P.Student else P.Regular end) as PriceToPay
from Prices P inner join Customer C on P.Movie = C.Movie) xxx
Group by Movie, MovieDate, MovieTime
```